# Understanding the vertices in Cauchy's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

How to guess the contour vertices in Cauchy's integral.
What would be the  vertices for this integral and why? :$$\oint_C dx \, x \, e^{-x^2}$$

Is the vertices means that they limit the contour so we use them as limit in the integration?

Comment: You have to specify the contour $C$ in order for any of this to make sense.

Comment: @T.Bongers, haven't got you.

Comment: If you don't say what $C$ is, then how can you say what the vertices are?

Answer (score 6):

In general, a curve integral doesn't really make sense without knowing what curve we are integrating along.

However, in this particular case, $f(z) = ze^{-z^2}$ is entire (holomorphic on the whole complex plane) and the notation "$\oint$" suggests that $C$ is a closed simple curve. Hence the integral is $0$ regardless of the choice of $C$.

In fact, we don't even need Cauchy's theorem for this, since $f(z) = F'(z)$ where $F(z) = -\frac12 e^{-z^2}$, and it follows from the complex version of the fundamental theorem of calculus that the integral over any closed curve is $0$.